How to Automatically Update Rows in a Vue.js Table with Real-Time Data?
Sure, here's the translation:
Hello, I have a question. I want to build a simple editor similar to Excel, which should function like Excel. Data should be automatically saved in the database whenever a cell value changes. Currently, I have it set up so that when I edit a cell, I have to click the save button for the value to be updated in the database. Im new here. I hope you can help me and thank you   Here is the code its not the complete code but i hope it helps:
<div>
  <v-toolbar>
    <v-dialog>
      <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          color="orange"
          dark
          depressed
          :loading="exportCSVLoader"
          class="mb-2 mx-2"
          @click="exportCSV"
        >
          Expotieren
        </v-btn>
        <ImportCSV
          :import-c-s-v-loader="importCSVLoader"
          @csv-data="getImportFileData"
        />

        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          dark
          depressed
          class="mb-2"
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
          Neues hinzufügen
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
          dark
          color="red"
          :loading="deleteButtonLoader"
          depressed
          class="mb-2 mx-1"
          @click="deleteItem(deleteItemRow)"
        >
          Löschen
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
          color="blue"
          dark
          :loading="saveButtonLoader"
          depressed
          class="mb-2 mx-1"
          @click="SaveExcelRecord(editedRow)"
        >
          Speichern
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="text-h5">{{ formTitle }}</span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-container>
            <HouseTextFields :edited-item="editedItem" @clear="close" />
          </v-container>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close"> Abrechen </v-btn>
          <v-btn
            :loading="saveButtonLoader"
            color="blue darken-1"
            text
            @click="save"
          >
            {{ editedItem?.id ? 'Update' : 'Speichern' }}
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialogDelete" max-width="500px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="text-h5"
          >Bist du sicher diese Zeile zu löschen?</v-card-title
        >
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="closeDelete"
            >Abrechen</v-btn
          >
          <v-btn
            color="blue darken-1"
            text
            :loading="deleteButtonLoader"
            @click="deleteItemConfirm"
            >OK</v-btn
          >
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-toolbar>
  <v-divider></v-divider>
</div>
<vue-excel-editor
  ref="grid"
  v-model="dataItem"
  :new-if-bottom="false"
  :allow-add-col="true"
  :no-header-edit="true"
  width="100%"
  :localized-label="myLabels"
  filter-row
  @cell-click="onRowDataChange"
  @update="updateRow"
  @select="rowSelected"
>
  ...
</vue-excel-editor>

methods: {
  updateRow(val) {
    if (val && val.length > 0) {
      let arr = []

      val.forEach(row => {
        if (this.dataItem?.length) {
          this.dataItem.find(el => {
            if (el.$id === row.$id) {
              // delete $id.
              delete el['$id']

              // Change date format
              if (el.builddate)
                el.builddate = moment(el.builddate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
              if (el.lastrenovation)
                el.lastrenovation = moment(el.lastrenovation).format(
                  'YYYY-MM-DD'
                )

              if (el.created_at)
                el.created_at = moment(el.created_at).format('YYYY-MM-DD')

              if (el.updated_at)
                el.updated_at = moment(el.updated_at).format('YYYY-MM-DD')

              // Push in array
              arr.push(el)
            }
          })
        }
      })

      console.log('row', arr)
      this.editedRow.data = [...arr]
    }
  },

  async SaveExcelRecord() {
    if (!this.editedRow.data || this.editedRow.data.length === 0) {
      // this.initToast("Nothing to save.", "info");
      return 'no data'
    }

    this.saveButtonLoader = true

    try {
      // Assuming that the API supports batch update
      await axios.post(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/JsonBulk`,
        this.editedRow.data
      )
      this.initToast('Daten wurden aktualisiert und gespeichert!', 'success')

      // reset
      this.editedRow = {
        index: -1,
        data: []
      }

      // load all records
      this.getHouseRecords()

      this.close()
    } catch (error) {
      this.initToast('Daten konnten nicht aktualisiert werden', 'error')
    } finally {
      this.saveButtonLoader = false
    }
  }
}


You would need to perform your save function when the cell data changes.  You have an @update event on your excel table, which I assume fires when a cell is updated.   You would just need to call your save function as part of your response to the update event.  Not sure if you've tried this or what the trouble is.

Thank you for the suggestion. I'm not sure how to implement this change. Could you provide an example of how the code could look to call the save function in response to the update event? I’m having trouble figuring out how to integrate this with my current setup.
Thank you!

It's really quite simple.  In the function updateRow which you're already calling everytime the update event fires, the last line would be this.SaveExcelRecord().  You can probably also remove the code related to the button, e.g. setting saveButtonLoader

It worked. Thank you so much .
I have one last question... When I import large datasets, like 40k records or more, the editing and other operations become very slow. What can I do to ensure that the system remains fast and responsive even with very large datasets?

@Maria to ensure that the system remains fast and responsive even with very large datasets, you have to render the data as a virtualized list. So in this case each item is rendered on the fly as the user scrolls the list.
Vuetify has a component for this https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/virtual-scroller/
